# How can i start Camunda bpm by http://localhost:8080/?

Tags: java, localhost, camunda

i want to start Camunda bpm. so i execute start.bat file , but that file do not execute . it means that execute so fast and then it does not stay at my taskbar . then i enter http://localhost:8080/ but does not show login page. but also i defiend JAVA_HOME.
please help me to execute http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Do you suppose asking people on Stack Overflow who may or may not have experience with Camunda is a better idea than asking at the [Camunda forum](https://camunda.com/developers/) itself, where everyone uses Camunda? If your problem is just keeping a console window open, edit your BAT file and add `pause` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Run the file from the command line. Then you will see the error and have a better idea. You can also check the log file.